# Preloader while Php Loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a preloader while php file is loading using ajax.  Is it possible using jquery? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you initiate the request, you can add your loading stuff. Using the `complete` callback function, you can remove the loading stuff. It's pretty simple. Here's an example.

```
function loadSomething(url) {
    showLoading();

    $.ajax(url).complete(function(data) {
        hideLoading();

        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Where `showLoading()` and `hideLoading()` manage your preloader respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the arguments to jQuery.ajax to accomplish this; set up your preloader content as markup and make the CSS hide it by default, but get it to show when a class is added.

For example, let's say we've got a div which is our preloader. Inside it we have a message saying 'Loading'. CSS3 would allow us to auto animate the change from the class .preloader to .preloader.show, then all we have to do is add and remove those classes from the holder.

This would be the markup:

```
<div class="preloader">
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
</div>​
```

Then comes the CSS3:

```
    .preloader {
        /* written in CSS 3.0 */
        opacity: 0;
        font-size: 36px;

        -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
         -khtml-transition: 0.2s all;
           -moz-transition: 0.2s all;
            -ms-transition: 0.2s all;
             -o-transition: 0.2s all;
                transition: 0.2s all;

        -webkit-transform: scale( 0.1 );
           -moz-transform: scale( 0.1 );
            -ms-transform: scale( 0.1 );
             -o-transform: scale( 0.1 );
                transform: scale( 0.1 );
    }
    .preloader.show {
        opacity: 1;

        -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity;
           -moz-transition: 0.2s opacity;
            -ms-transition: 0.2s opacity;
             -o-transition: 0.2s opacity;
                transition: 0.2s opacity;

        -webkit-transform: scale( 1 );
         -khtml-transform: scale( 1 );
           -moz-transform: scale( 1 );
            -ms-transform: scale( 1 );
             -o-transform: scale( 1 );
                transform: scale( 1 );
    }
```

​
And finally the javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js',
        dataType: 'script',
        beforeSend: function(evt) {
            if ( ! $('.preloader').is('.show') ) $('.preloader').addClass('show');
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            // disable either here or at the end
            $('.preloader').removeClass('show');

            // handle error and success
        }
});
```

});
​

I uploaded this example @ JSFiddle for you, here's the source: http://jsfiddle.net/8XP9r/15/

and here is what it would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/8XP9r/15/embedded/result/

Tell me how things go! XD